# If I write an erotic / porn novel now, what are the chances that it might impact my mainstream writing career?

Tags: novel, career, erotica

Given that I have written a few erotic / porn novels now, what are the chances that it will impact my mainstream writing career later? Even if I do write using a pen name, will people be willing to accept it?

Comment: If you use a pen name, how will they know?

Comment: Good Point .... but lets say .... if it comes out accidentally ....

Comment: I'd certainly consider the possibility that someone will figure it out sooner or later. Lots of people have gotten burned because they assumed that no one would ever know they did X because they took some steps to keep it secret.

Comment: Nobody cares, really they don't.

Answer (score 6):

Anne Rice wrote four erotic novels using pseudonyms -- *Exit to Eden* under the pen name Anne Rampling and the *Sleeping Beauty* trilogy under the name A.N. Roquelaire -- and they don't seem to have hurt her career.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of depends on what you want to do later in your career. For instance if you want to write something about the church, your erotic novels might stand in your way. But as a novelist, I doubt they will have any negative effect on your career. Especially if you support them yourself. People wouldn't care if they enjoy your novels. It's not like you killed someone.

Answer (score 1):

To add another example, [Kouta Hirano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kouta_Hirano) and [Type-Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-Moon) both started out making erotic works. Hirano wrote straight-up hentai and Type-Moon's original works were eroge. Both of their pasts aren't greatly hidden, and in fact the later non-pornographic works they are more famous for (*Hellsing* and *Fate/Stay Night* and *Tsukihime*) actually involve *the exact same* characters they used in their original erotic works. [There's actually a lot of authors that do this](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BleachedUnderpants) ranging from The Foglios and Osamu Tezuka to Roald Dahl and *Dr. frigging Seuss*.

Comment: Worth noting that *Fate/Stay Night* (and probably *Tsukihime*) still have graphic sex scenes. They're just far smaller portions of the work (and infamously badly-written).

Comment: @F1Krazy IIRC Fate/Stay Night removed or downplayed most of them from the more recent retellings. It remains to be seen whether Tsukihime will do the same with the upcoming reboot.